# Is ～がる suffix limited to specific adjectives only?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

I noticed that there are some adjectives that have ～がる suffix to make them into verbs. Some examples from WWWJDIC:

> ほしがる
>   こわがる
>   いたがる
>   くるしがる
>   さびしがる
>   うれしがる

Apparently ～たい form also can take the ～がる suffix to become ～たがる suffix:

> いきたがる

Rikaichan popup explains the ～がる as:

> to feel (on adj-stem to represent third party's apparent emotion); to behave as if one were

So I thought that I could append this suffix to any adjectives to add those connotations. However, it seems that not all adjectives and ～たい have the suffix. WWWJDIC does not return any exact matches for the following words:

> やさしがる  (to behave as if one were nice?)
>   きたがる  (to feel that one wants to come? - Since いきたがる exists so logically きたがる should exist too?)
>   ねむがる (to behave as if one were sleepy?)

My question is, as in the title, is ～がる suffix limited to specific adjectives only? How do we know which adjectives can have the suffix and which adjectives can't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained by the Rikaichan popup you reference in your question, ～がる is a suffix for representing a third party's *apparent **emotion***. As such, you cannot use it with やさしい or ねむい as these are not adjectives which describe emotions.

As it was explained to me, you cannot generally *know* another person's emotions or thoughts, and so when speaking of them, you use either ～がる (e.g. うれしがる) or ～そう (e.g. うれしそう). To some extent, this is true even in English -- "John seems sad today" seems more generally applicable than "John is sad today" (without John having said so himself).

**To answer your question:** you use this for adjectives (including ～たい) which represent emotional or psychological states. It's very difficult to provide an exhaustive list of such adjectives.

Comment: As for an instance of 来たがる, how about the following?  You are at a concert or a party and talking about your friend who is not there: 山田さんも来たがっていたけれど、残念ながら仕事で来られないんだ。  Since you are there, 行きたがっていた would sound strange in this example.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I think I would lean more toward 山田さんも来たかったそうだけれど (likely this is my own failing)... But you make a good point.

Comment: @rintaun @Tsuyoshi: I can understand why the adjectives need to be related to emotion in order to use the -garu suffix. What strikes me as strange is that the suffix is also selective on the -tai form, which is related to emotion (as in, to desire to do something is related to emotion).

Comment: @Lukman: As I understand it, the ～たい suffix is, for all intents and purposes, an i-adjective.

Comment: @rintaun: Suppose that 山田さん did not tell you explicitly that he/she wanted to come to the concert, but instead it was obvious that he/she wanted to come from what he/she said or did.  (Maybe 山田さん is a little childish.)  In this case, 来たがっていた describes the situation more accurately than 来たかったそうだ.  (But depending on the context, the use of -たがる can be impolite because it implies that the desire of the subject is apparent from his/her behavior.)

Comment: I see. So can I say, all -tai adjectives can have -garu suffix, but for normal i-adjectives only those that relate to showing emotion can have the suffix?

Comment: @Lukman: That is correct, as far as I know.

Comment: “Apparent emotion” is a good explanation, but it does not explain everything.  For example, 強がる means to try to act tough, but I think that it is a stretch to say that 強い (strong) is an emotion.  I doubt that there is a perfect explanation why 強がる is used and 優しがる is not.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi WWWJDIC translates 強がる as "to pretend to be tough" .. so what is your opinion about using 優しがる to say "to pretend to be nice"? Can the existence of 強がる be used as an excuse that 優しがる should exist too?

Comment: @Lukman: If someone uses the word 優しがる, I am not sure if I can understand the meaning.  Whether the word 優しがる “should exist” or not is a moot point because it is not used and (at least for me) it is probably not understandable.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi How do you say "to pretend to be nice" then?

Comment: @Lukman: I would say 優しいふりをする.