# Can たい be used to express desire for 2nd person

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

Can たい be used to express desire for a 2nd person to do something. For example:

> I want you to come back
>
> 戻り**たい**

I realise the proper way to do this is to use あなたに戻って欲しい, but was just wondering if たい is also proper.

Comment: If you say あなたに戻りたい it just sounds like **I** want to go back **to** you, where the に becomes "to".

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41564/1628

Comment: @Ben edited again

Comment: @Earthliŋ Doesn't really answer the question of whether it can be used for second person

Comment: @donburi In my answer to the linked question you can find the answer (〜たい should be used for first person, and second person is not the same as first person). In any case, I'm confused by this question, since you seem to know how to say it with 戻ってほしい, but you're wondering if you can use 戻りたい instead...?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I know the proper way is to use して欲しい but am curious whether たい can also be used for 2nd person. Sometimes, there are more than 1 way to say the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to express desire for a 2nd person to do something, you can use these phrase, Aに～してほしい or Aに～してもらいたい. So you can say あなたに戻ってきてもらいたい or あなたに戻ってきてほしい.

Comment: Thanks. Don't want to be a party pooper but I already knew that. The question that I am interested in is, can verb + たい, ie: 戻りたい be used for a 2nd person. In other words,戻りたい translates to "I want you to come back"

Comment: Do you ask that 私は、あなたに戻りたい can be translated as  "I want you to come back"? No, it can't be and doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know 戻りたい can mean "I want to come back", but I am asking if 戻りたい can also mean "I want you to come back"

Comment: No, it can't. 戻りたい means "I want to come back".

Comment: あざっす。全然ダメのことっすか。"て...欲しい"ってなんか硬いと思いますので..

Comment: もっとカジュアルに言いたいのなら、"戻ってきて"だけでも通じるよ。

Answer (score 2):

> Can たい be used to express desire for a 2nd person to do something.

No. The 〜たい form to express a desire or wish can only be used to express *your own* feelings and applies only to the 1st person ("I"). In particular, if you say

> 戻りたい

it will always be interpreted as you yourself wanting to return / go back.

If you want to talk about someone else (2nd person "you" or 3rd person "he/she/it") you have to use other forms of expression, such as 〜て欲しい (if you want someone else to do something) or 〜たがる (to describe what someone else seems to want/desire).

For more information see

- [Can たい and たがる be used for a 1st/2nd/3rd person's desire?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23860/1628)
- [What difference between ほしい (hoshii) and したい (shitai)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41564/1628)
- [Is ～がる suffix limited to specific adjectives only?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1520/1628)